# Confusion: nil in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, param

I am working on iOS app and usually use Objective C and little ruby. So suppose I have the below code in Objective C:

```
if ([!propertyA isEqual:propertyB])
{
// Execute logic in here.
}
```

If my propertyA is nil, my condition for if would be nil and logic inside the it would not be executed.

However I am trying to check similar thing in ruby and this time the logic inside if gets executed when while my first parameter is nil.

***Ruby Code:***

```
if params[:some_param] != params[:other_param]
# Execute this logic
end
```

In my parameters list, I don't have 'some_param' and hence when the above if code is executed it's more like:

```
if nil != params[:other_name]
```

This condition comes out to be true and logic inside if is executed. However if I add a check for params[:some_param] before comparing the two, then logic inside if is not executed which is what I want.

So will I always have to check if the param is present or not? Shouldn't `nil != params[:other_name]` result into nil and avoid the execution inside if?

I am just trying to avoid the extra param check here.

Comment: I think you can't avoid double check in Ruby.

Comment: I'm assuming that Objective-C example is meant to be `if (![propertyA isEqual:propertyB])`. If so, the code inside the brackets *will* execute if `propertyA` is nil, because `[nil isEqual:propertyB]` gives 0, and `!0` is 1. (The code as written here is not actually valid with `propertyA` as nil, because negating NULL doesn't yield a valid pointer.)

Answer (score 0):

You  are using a boolean so it won't evaluate to nil

You could do this

```
if params.fetch(:some_param, params[:other_param]) != params[:other_param]
```

fetch returns a default if :some_param is nil, this way you'd get equality and the logic would be skipped, not sure it's expressive in this case.

that way you'd be comparing apples to apples

Generally, it's good to use fetch with sensible defaults instead of nil checking